# Unity3D - Visualized field of view cone does not rotate correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visualization, mesh

I wrote a simple code for visualizing cone of view. It works quite all right, but when I rotate my object 90 degrees, cone of view is "behind" the object while I would expect it to be on the right.
[image: 1][image: 2]

This is the whole code I've got for visualizing cone of view:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class FieldOfView : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Mesh fieldOfViewMesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;
    private Vector2[] uv;
    private int[] triangles;

    public float fieldOfView = 70.0f;
    public float fieldOfViewDistance = 7.0f;
    public int rayCount = 32;

    void Start()
    {
        fieldOfViewMesh = new Mesh();
        fieldOfViewMesh.name = "fieldOfViewMesh";
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = fieldOfViewMesh;

        vertices = new Vector3[rayCount + 2];
        uv = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        triangles = new int[rayCount * 3];
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        fieldOfViewMesh.Clear();
        vertices[0] = transform.localPosition;

        for (int i=0; i<=rayCount; i++)
        {
            vertices[i + 1] = transform.localPosition
                + VectorFromAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y - fieldOfView / 2.0f + fieldOfView / rayCount * i).normalized * fieldOfViewDistance;

            if (i > 0 && i < rayCount)
            {
                triangles[i * 3 + 0] = 0;
                triangles[i * 3 + 1] = i - 1;
                triangles[i * 3 + 2] = i;
            }
        }

        fieldOfViewMesh.vertices = vertices;
        fieldOfViewMesh.uv = uv;
        fieldOfViewMesh.triangles = triangles;
    }

    Vector3 VectorFromAngle(float inputAngle)
    {
        return Quaternion.AngleAxis(inputAngle, transform.up) * transform.forward;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Is it something with converting degrees to radians (or lack of it)?

Comment: One thing I spotted is that I'm not normalizing vector from VectorFromAngle. It still doesn't fix it, though. Now when I rotate my object 90 degrees, the viewcone faces the direction it should face when the object would be rotated -90 degrees. Rotating object 180 degrees works all right.
EDIT: I edited my original post with two changes - instead of localEulerAngles, I'm using eulerAngles. And I also normalize the vector I'm getting from VectorFromAngle().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Seems it was a mistake to use localPosition. I used position with InverseTransformPoint() and now it works all right.